# twitter api how to fav a tweet?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, twitter

I use Matt Gemmels Twitter Engine in my app and I wanted to know if there's a method that favs a tweet which is shown?

Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`favorites/create/:id`](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/favorites/create/%3aid)

In the library you use there will be probably some method to access this directly. I have found this method in the source, which is probably what you are looking for. I can't give you an exact example as I neither use the library nor know enough about the language:

```
(NSString *)markUpdate:(MGTwitterEngineID)updateID asFavorite:(BOOL)flag; // favorites/create, favorites/destroy
```

So it should work something like this:

```
[twitterEngine markUpdate:ID asFavorite:true];
```

Comment: are there any examples for that?